# Trying to substract from 2D list WITHOU numpy

Tags: python, list, 2d

I have read through many solutions but none work for me, I think I am missing something.

I am trying to subtract 5 from every element of a 2D list array for an exercise. Not allowed to use numpy. I try to use list comprehension but I get an error.

Specifically my code is:

```
list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]    
res=[]
for i in range (len(list)):
row=[]
        for j in range(len(list[i])):
            row.append(5 - list[i][j])
        res.append(row)
```

When I run the .py file I get the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `res=[[5-x for x in y] for y in list]`

Comment: Sorry what is y in this statement? And do you mean I don't need a for loop at all?

Comment: y will be each of inner lists. Yes, you can get your result by this way

Comment: Really, it is an other form of the same tow for loops

Comment: Thank you so much! I created a new file with just what you wrote and it works. In my existing one I still get the same error so I must be missing something else. Thank you again!